# Newbie question: NSOperation for iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, nsoperation

Hi I got some problem with NSOperation .
I always got error at `self = [super init];` (already use break point to find this)
it always return "Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" all the time

```
//AddThread.h
@interface AddThread : NSOperation
{
    NSString * str;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * str;
-(id) initWithString:(NSString *) tmpStr;
@end
```

and for .m

```
//AddThread.m
#import "AddThread.h"
@implementation AddThread
@synthesize str;
- (id) initWithString:(NSString *)tmpStr
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.str = tmpStr;
    }
    //NSLog(self);
    //[super init];
        return self;
}
- (void) main
{
    NSLog(self.str);
}
- (void) dealloc{
    [str release];
    str = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

well I stuck with this for while and if possible any resources ,articles things for basic example of NSoperation?

Answer (score 1):

In your main method, you are calling `NSLog(self.str)` - While this will work if the object you pass in is a string, it won't work if you continue to try and log other objects. NSLog takes a format string as a parameter. If you just do `NSLog(self)` like you are in some of your commented code, and self is not a string, it'll crash because it expected a string. You should do `NSLog(@"self: %@", self)` the %@ will print out the string returned by an objects `description` method.

Other than that, your init method looks fine, how exactly are you creating an instance of this object? Could you show the code for that? The problem may lie there.